# How to average a point cloud object groups to a single centroid point?

Tags: python, lidar, point-cloud, point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud data. What I want to do is count how many objects are there in the point cloud.

[image: sample model]

Suppose there are many cylindrical objects in my point cloud. What I am thinking of doing is to average each point cloud objects( which will be a tight packed group of points) to a single centroid point(orange). Then counting the centroids will be the number of objects in the point cloud.

How can this actually be done? Are there any Python libraries which can read, do this operation, and write from/to point clouds?

Comment: What are the cylindrical objects in real life? Trees?

Comment: @BERA Yes, when  cut the top and bottom, the trunks should look like cylinders.

Comment: A possible R solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355169/calculate-volume-of-a-building-using-lidar-data

Comment: @BERA thanks but I don't know R. Not even the basics.